# Factory reset Canon iSensys MF635cx

Tags: network-printer

I am trying to login in as System ID but I have forgotten the username and password

Defaults id & pass (7654321) are not working because, if I remember correctly, I changed them when I installed it.

Is there a way to factory reset and use the defaults again?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [User Manual](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/laser/laserbase_mf_series/i-sensys_mf635cx.html?type=manuals&manualid=tcm:14-1560973), you can do a factory reset by following these steps:

> This enables restoration of all data and machine settings, including logs, to the factory default values. This prevents sensitive data from being leaked when replacing or disposing of the machine. When the initialization process finishes, the machine automatically restarts.
>
> - Before initializing, make sure that there are no documents being processed or waiting to be processed. These documents will be deleted when initialization is performed.
> - To use the machine after initializing it, you need to configure all settings from the beginning.

1. On the home screen of the operation panel, press the right arrow.
2. Press *Menu*
3. Press *Management Settings*
4. Press *Initialize All Data/Settings*
5. Press *Yes*
6. Press *Yes*, again

The printer should automatically restart and all default factory settings should be restored and will need to be reconfigured.

Comment: Yes, so this works if you _lost_ your pincode (which I have). In which case this would help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOhFyqYO9-8. Press HOME, press left of home (between the little moon icon en home), press right of home (between home and the red icon), press the volume button, press the red icon. Go to Function > All > press Yes. Wait. Turn off the Printer. Turn on again and you can set everything again.